# Save bash output from asynchronous api requests to a file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, curl

I am trying to save the output of this *iterative asynchronous curl requests* to a file. When I am running the code given below synchronously (by **removing &**) everything works well and responses are stored on the given file. But during asynchronous curl request the data is shown in the bash command line itself and not stored on the file.

Here is my code snippet!

```
for i in {1..300}
do
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  --data-binary '{"level0":"data1"}' \
  --compressed & >> file.json
done
```

Note: The `&` in my request made it asynchronous request to the API.
Also, my api endpoint responds once every 2 second(if that's important)!

Comment: Put the `&` after the redirection.

Comment: But it makes the code synchronous and waits for response, if i put & after the redirection, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you @muru. I think that solved it!